# Postback to controller action from ajax not working?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

this is my ajax call:

```
$('#SaveItemButton').click(function () {   
        var tableData = { 'ItemViewModel': table.$('input, select').serialize() }; // here the data gets returned          
        //Add Data Function
        function Add() {                    
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Item/Add",
                data: tableData,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success: " + result);
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert("error: " + errormessage);
                }
            });
        }       
    } );
```

And this is my controller action:

```
public JsonResult Add(List<ItemViewModel> ItemViewModel)
{
   var x = ItemViewModel;               
   return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

actual data returned by **tableData**: 
     "`ItemType=Type1&Unit=select&Quantity=12&Price=1000&Total=&ItemType=Type2&Unit=//select&Quantity=11&Price=2000&Total="`

my controller action is receiving ItemViewModel = null. Can anyone tell me what I need to do with the data received so I can successful postback to the server and bind to the model:

```
public class ItemViewModel
    {        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ItemType { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ServiceViewModel> Services { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CustomerViewModel> Customers { get; set; }
        public InvoiceViewModel Invoice { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }        
        public int ProductId { get; set; }       
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }       
        public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public string TransferDate { get; set; }
        public string TransferPlace { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceDescription { get; set; }        
    }
```

This is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Item", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "ItemForm", role = "form" }))
{
    <body>
        <h2>Invoice</h2>

        <table id="ItemTable" class="table table-hover table-secondary" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>ItemType</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

    </body>
}
```

And this is the jquery DataTable, javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#ItemTable').DataTable({
        "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
        "paging": true,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "searching": false,
        responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column'
            }
        },
        columnDefs: [{
            className: 'control',
            orderable: false,
            targets: 0
        }],
        order: [1, 'asc']
    });

    $("div.toolbar").html(
        '<button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info fa fa-plus"> Add</button> <div class="divider"/>' +
        '<button id="SaveItemButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary fa fa-save"> Save</button> <div class="divider"/>' +
        '<button id="PreviewButton" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info fa fa-eye"> Preview</button> <div class="divider"/>' +
        '<button id="PrintButton" type="button" class="btn btn-info fa fa-print"> Print</button> <div class="divider"/>' +
        '<button id="SendButton" type="button" class="btn btn-lump-sum fa fa-envelope"> Send</button> <div class="divider"/>' +
        '<button id="DeleteButton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary fa fa-trash"> Delete </button> <div class="divider"/>'
    );

    var counter = 1;

    $('#addRow').on('click', function () {
        table.row.add([
            '',
            '<input name="ItemType" class="form-control" type="text">',

            '<select name="Unit" class="form-control defaultpicker">' +
                '<option value="select">dan</option>' + 
                '<option value="select">Komad</option>' +
                '<option value="select">Sat</option>' +
                '<option value="select">m</option>' +
                '<option value="select">m2</option>' +
                '<option value="select">m3</option>' +
                '<option value="select">kg</option>' +
                '<option value="select">lit</option>' +
                '<option value="select">pak</option>' +
                '<option value="select">reč</option>' +                               
            '</select > ',

            '<input name="Quantity" class="form-control" type="number">',
            '<input name="Price" class="form-control" type="text">',
            '<input name="Total" class="form-control" type="text" readonly>',
            '<button type="button" Id="DeleteButton" class="fa fa-times select-row btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-id=""></button>',            
        ]).draw(false);

        counter++;
        $('#ItemTable').dataTable().fnPageChange('last');
    });

    $('#ItemTable').on("click", "#DeleteButton", function () {
        var table = $('#ItemTable').DataTable();
        var row;

        console.log($(this).closest('table'));
        if ($(this).closest('table').hasClass("collapsed")) {
            var child = $(this).parents("tr.child");
            row = $(child).prevAll(".parent");
        } else {
            row = $(this).parents('tr');
        }

        table.row(row).remove().draw();
    });

    // Automatically add a first row of data
    $('#addRow').click();    

    $('#SaveItemButton').click(function () {
        debugger;
        //Add Data Function
        function Add() {                    
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Item/Add",
                data: table.$('input, select').serialize(),
                type: "POST",                
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success: " + result);
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert("error: " + errormessage);
                }
            });
        }       
    } );
});
```

Comment: You cannot combine `.serialize()` and an object (and `contentType: "application/json"` does not work with `.serialize()`  anyway. You can just use `data: table.$('input, select').serialize(),` and delete the `contentType` option

Comment: But the parameter in your method is a collection, but you do not seem to be posting an array. You will need to show us what the view looks like.

Comment: Using `List<ItemViewModel> ItemViewModel` as action POST argument requires array serialization of entire form contents, but current POST request seem not to include all form elements (usually with `$('form').serialize()`). Also `contentType: "application/json"` usage is pointless here - a standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` should be used.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, still returning null, I have updated the question above to show the "view" part.

Comment: The `name` attributes of your dynamic form controls have no relationship to a collection (they need zero based collection indexers (e.g. `name="[0].Quantity"` etc), otherwise you are going to have to loop through the items to build an array, stringify it and send it using `contentType: "application/json"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have tried: JSON.stringify(table.$('input, select').serializeArray()); and JSON.stringify(table.$('input, select').serialize()); they both return null in contoller action.

Comment: No you cannot do that. You will need to iterate each `<tr>`, build an object, and add it to an array. Give me 30 min or so and I will add an answer (and as a side note, all your `<option>` elements have `value="select"` which does not make much sense)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Ok thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use combine `.serialize()` inside a javascript object, and when using `.serialize()`, you need to use the default `contentType` (`'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`) in any case.

One option would be to include the  collection indexer in the name attribute, so that the `name` attributes of you form controls are `name="[#].ItemType"` where `#` is a zero based, consecutive indexer, in which case the ajax call can be

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Item/Add",
    data: table.$('input, select').serialize(),
    type: "POST",
    ....
```

however since you also appear to want to delete items, that also means you need to add an input for the collection indexer (e.g. `<input name="Index" value="#">`) in each row.

Alternatively, you need to generate and array of objects based on the values of each form control in each `<tr>`, stringify it, and send it using `contentType: 'application/json'`

To build the array

```
var arr = [];
// adjust following to exclude any tr elements in a thead or tfoot if applicable
var rows = $('#ItemTable').find('tr');
$.each(rows, function(index, item) {
    var controls = $(this).find('input, select');
    var item = {
        ItemType: controls.eq(0).val(),
        Unit: controls.eq(1).val(),
        Quantity: controls.eq(2).val(),
        Price controls.eq(3).val(),
    }
    arr.push(item);
});
```

And then to post it

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Item")', // don't hard code your urls
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: "POST",                
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        ....
```

As a side note, you are creating a `<select>` with `name="Unit"` but there does not appear to be a property in your model with that name. In addition, you have given each `<option>` the same `value="select"`

Comment: table.find('<tr>');  is throwing an error table.find is not a function.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `$('#ItemTable').find('tr')`

Comment: Note I am not sure if your html includes a `<tbody>`, but it would be best to use that as the selector, so you exclude any rows in the `<thead>` etc

Comment: I think i have a problem with DataTable not returning rows with $('#ItemTable').find('tr') also.

Comment: Just have a look at the actual html that is being generated (you must have `<tr>` elements, so not sure what issue your having - are you saying `rows.length` returns 0?

Comment: debugger does not get to that part it just snaps and goes to the controller immediately.

Comment: And just as a side note, why are you using DataTables for this (its not really suitable when editing data) and you will have other issues relating to validation (your not getting any client side validation at all, and its not clear what your going to do if there are server side validation errors)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178070/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-dusan).